# Angular not display ing data data

Tags: angularjs

i have 1 **data.json**  file .like {"name":"K.m.ullah", "city":"Chi", "age":22, "parmanentAdderess":"Sathb","presentAddress":"web ","phone":}.
i want to display detail data in another page**`templateUrl:'partial/view1.html**',` by by calling ***name***.my **controller.json** file are below

```
var newappt = angular.module('newappt', ['ngRoute']);


newappt.config(function ($routeProvider){
$routeProvider
    .when('/',
    {
        templateUrl:'partial/view.html',
        controller:'simpleController'


    })
    .when('/view1',
    {
        templateUrl:'partial/view1.html',
        controller:'simpleController'


    })
    .when('/view2',
    {
        controller:'simpleController',
        templateUrl:'partial/view2.html'

    })
    .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
}); 

newappt.controller('simpleController', function($scope,$http){
$http.get('data.json').success(function(cust){
$scope.customer=cust;
});
```

Comment: can you be more clear ? i can not understand exactly what you need

Comment: suppose main i page i displya name =jon when i click  i click jon then i will see detal about jon

Comment: Provide working example (that means including html). Btw, I hope you meant controller.js?

Answer (score 0):

template for view.html:

```
  <a href="#/view1">{{customer.name}}</a>
```

template for view1.html:

```
<p>
  name: {{customer.name}} <br/>
  city: {{customer.city}}<br/>
  age: {{customer.age}}<br/>
  parmanentAdderess:{{customer.parmanentAdderess}}<br/>
  presentAddress:{{customer.presentAddress}}<br/>
  phone: {{customer.phone}}<br/>
</p>
```

sample demo here :
http://plnkr.co/edit/29VtLjbp7Y6yIGQqUH3c?p=preview

Comment: but i want just data  not all json data .in your answer tjis show alll alll with ,""{}

Comment: when i click k.m.ullh then view1 page will show k.m.ull ,22,kfaj@gmail.com

Comment: {"name":"K.m. ullah","city":"Ching","age":2,"parmanentAdderess":"Satharam para,Chandaong","presentAddress":"web cka","phone":18201,"position":"web Dper","bloodGroup":"B+","email":"rjad@gmail.com"},

Comment: yes you are rigth but when (k.m.ull) and (jon) are two when i clik jon then i see john detal when i click k,m.ulla then i see k.m.ullah detail.i want this

Comment: thanks yes that is right,please give link how can i learn best about angular